# Let $E/F$ be a finite field extension, $E,F$ are finite, $\operatorname{Char}{F}=p\nmid [E:F]$. Prove $E/F$ is separable.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, finite-fields

**My attempt**:

$\operatorname{Char}{F}=p>0$ then $F, E$ are finite, hence $F\cong \mathbb F_{p^n}, E\cong \mathbb F_{p^m}, n\mid m$
and we have extensions tower $\mathbb F_{p}\subset F\subset E$.
$E/\mathbb F_p$ is separable as the splitting field of $f(X)=X^{p^m}-X$ over $\mathbb F_p$.

From a theorem, given this extensions tower, $\mathbb F_{p}\subset F\subset E$,
if $E/\mathbb F_p$ is separable, then so is $E/F$, as requested $\square$

I didn't use the fact that $\operatorname{Char}{F}=p\nmid [E:F]$.
Does my proof still hold?

**EDIT:**
I'm aware of this solution: [Every finite extension of a finite field is separable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/260426/every-finite-extension-of-a-finite-field-is-separable)
However, $\operatorname{Char}{F}=p\nmid [E:F]$ is not mentioned, hence my issue is not solved.
Does pointing out $\operatorname{Char}{F}=p\nmid [E:F]$ has any significance in this problem?

**Solution:**
$\operatorname{Char}{F}=p\nmid [E:F]$ is a redundant detail for this problem, the statement holds for any $\operatorname{Char}{F}$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/260426/every-finite-extension-of-a-finite-field-is-separable

Comment: Thank you, @TsemoAristide, but it doesn't answer my question. My question regards my proof and its validity despite not using $\operatorname{Char}{F}=p\nmid [E:F]$. In the link you attached, they don't concern this data.

Comment: Your question illustrates why you shouldn't use the phrasing "finite field extension." Is it a finite extension of fields? Or an extension of finite fields? You write "$\operatorname{char}(F) = p > 0$ then $F, E$ are finite," but this implication is not true. For instance, consider $\mathbb{F}_p(t)$, the field of rational functions over $\mathbb{F}_p$, which has characteristic $p$ but is infinite.

Comment: In addition to saying $E/F$ is a finite extension, I stated "$E,F$ are finite" in the headline as a part of the data given in the problem

Comment: I guess the statement of the problem is incorrect. If $E$ is a finite field, extension of the field $F$, then obviously also $F$ is finite as well as $[E:F]$. Any finite field is separable over its prime subfield, so also over any intermediate subfield. The problem that makes sense is “suppose $E/F$ is a finite extension of (not necessarily finite) fields with characteristic $p>0$; if $p\nmid[E:F]$ then $E$ is separable over $F$”.

Comment: My point exactly. Thanks you, @egreg :-)

Comment: The hypothesis that the degree be prime to $p$ is extraneous, i.e. unnecessary.