# Algebraic closure of Zp

Tags: galois-theory, galois-extensions

So there I have this problem:

> Let $p$ be a prime number. Denote by E the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$. Prove that:
>
> a) Every finite subfield F of E is a Galois extension of $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$.
>
> b) For each positive integer n, there exists a subfield F of E such that the Galois group Gal(F,$\mathbb{Z}_{p}$) has order n and is also a solvable group.

For question a, I'm thinking of showing the normality and seperability of F. For b then I dont know how to start yet. Can I get any hint for the problem please?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/260426/every-finite-extension-of-a-finite-field-is-separable

Comment: Just because $E$ is Galois over $\Bbb Z_p$, that does _not_ mean that any finite intermediate extension is Galois.

Comment: the main obstacle for me is that the problem requires working on a field of char p, which I rarely work with (most of the time I do exercises about extension over Q), so I just have no idea what to do.